# angular 6 production main.ts file size

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, ng-build

hi i built my angular 6 app by :

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer --stats-json
```

command and here is my result ..check this image:

my app have many component the main.ts file size is little high even if i use gzip user must download at least 1 meg   ...

i want to know 2 thing:

1.accroding my image the size of production files are normal ???

2- any way to reduce the main.ts size ??

merci

[image: result for build]

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "m4new",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "analyze": "ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/m4user/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.1.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.8.6",
    "@mdi/font": "^2.2.43",
    "angular-typing-animation": "^0.5.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "mdi": "^2.2.43",
    "ngx-uploader": "^4.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "videogular2": "^6.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1"
  }
}
```

///////////////////////////////webpackanalyzer image //////////////:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your package.json?

Comment: yes i added it to post

Comment: How many components and modules do you have?

Comment: remove your rxjs-compat if any of your dependencies is still using it.

Comment: According to your dependencies and if your application is quite big then such result should be right. What does `webpack-bundle-analyzer` show you?

Comment: there is many component  i will add analyzer for you

Comment: post updated please check the analyzer result

Comment: Are you still using @angular/http?

Comment: yes this is rest project im using it to send request to server and i use httpincepter  to add jwt to header

Comment: Have you tried HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http?

Comment: yes i imported it from angular/common/http

Comment: Almost half of bundle size is your code. To reduce the size you should reduce the code of generated ngFactories. To do that you should reduce html of your components. Also consider using lazy loading especially for admin

Comment: Then some of your dependencies uses @angular/http

Comment: Maybe you do not need all locales shipped by momentjs?

Comment: i used global search for @angular/http i didnt find any thing that is using it .. is there a way to find it?

Comment: i used a pipe for moment js to change date format is it wrong way ?

Comment: I would begin with removing `"@angular/http": "^6.0.0",` `from package.json`

Comment: shoulld i remove rxjs-compat or @angular/http  or anyhing else?

Comment: https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack But for that you need to have access to webpack.config.js

Comment: Seems some of your dependencies requires `rxjs-compat ` so i don't think it will work after you remove it

Comment: i removed @angular/http build size have no change . . i check the link about momentjs optimize now thanks

Comment: Try to apply `--no-sourcemap` with `ng build`.

Comment: it say Unknown option: '--sourcemap'

Comment: in angular 6 this options are enable by default in angular json file:
`
       "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
` so no need to tell cli again